# Perl string from regex is different from created string - breaks fgrep

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I have a piece of code which is checking if a filename givne in a file is present in a master list but it keeps saying the string isn't there when it is - but if I declare a second variable with the filename in it - manually typed - it works fine.

The variable that came from the regex is not the same as the one I declared (they look the same).  I checked this but with Perl's automatic type parsing I am at a loss to understand what the issue is.

```
...
open (my $fh_in, $in_file) or die "Could not open file $in_file $!";

seek ($fh_in, 5995, 0);
my $line = readline ($fh_in);
$line =~ /"([^"]*)"/;  # extracts the filename from a Filename="..." field
my $adf_file = $1;

if (fgrep { /$adf_file/ } "masterlist.txt" ) {
  print "The file is in the master list\n";
} else {
  print "It isn't\n";
}
```

It says the file is not in the master list.
If instead I do:

```
my $testst = "File_I_Want";

fgrep { /$testst/ }   ...
```

It says the file is in the master list.

Also if I then compare:

```
if ($testst eq $adf_file) {
  print "variables are the same\n";
} else {
  print "variables are not the same\n";
}
```

Is printing that they differ but they look identical.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;  print Dumper $adf_file;` and show the results.

Comment: Yeah, do that. It will reveal any unprintable characters in `$adf_file`.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I'll remember that for the future - there's some trailing whitespace. $VAR1 = "ASA_CON_AXVIEC20120626_153045_20030601_000000_20050916_195733 ";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will help to see the differences between your two strings if you add

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Dumper $adf_file;
```

Setting the `Useqq` option makes `Data::Dumper` present strings in double-quoted style, using escape sequences for all non-printable characters.

Better still is [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump), which requires just

```
use Data::Dump;
dd $adf_file;
```

to do the same thing. It also produces much more nicely readable displays of nested data structures, but it isn't a core module and will probably need installing.